# jquery accordion systematicaly open after two iterations

Tags: jquery, iteration, accordion

I'm using a jquery accordion I remade from a tutorial on Learning Jquery website:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/03/accordion-madness
And it works really fine, except when I put it in a loop. After two iterations, the accordion is displayed totally open and doesn't work at all...

Jasvascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//simultaneous showing and hiding
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.tiny-accordion:eq(0) > div').hide();
  $('div.tiny-accordion:eq(0) > h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  });

  $('div.tiny-accordion:eq(1) > div').hide();  
  $('div.tiny-accordion:eq(1) > h3').click(function() {
    var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
    var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

    if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
      $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
        $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
      });
    } else {
       $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
    }
  }); 
});
</script>
```

HTML which is a part of a big loop

```
<div class="tiny-accordion">
    <h3><div>1</div></h3>
    <div>
        <div class="line">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3><div>2</div></h3>
    <div>
        <div class="line">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>

        <h3><div>3</div></h3>
    <div>
        <div class="line">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* MENU ACCORDEON */
.tiny-accordion{
    width: 245px;
    position: relative;
 }

.tiny-accordion h3{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    height: 29px;
}

.tiny-accordion div{
background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

It seems to be a js problem because everything works fine in the loop, except the accordion.
I also tried to repeat the html code 3 and four times manually, and it's the same problem.
Here is a jsfiddle link :
http://jsfiddle.net/TF5AV/

Comment: Can you simulate the same in jsfiddle,so that it will be easier to rectify your prob .http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Small Suggestion,why you want to do your own accordion.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.tiny-accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true            
});
});
This should work for you http://jsfiddle.net/aVXyw/

Comment: Yes sorry, Here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/TF5AV/

Comment: @SAM He might be trying to try and get familiar with jQuery. He accidentally select a guide to create an accordion menu and begin with it. It does not matter whether it's worse, he may need to see what is wrong with his work

Comment: @SAM, thanks your accordion seems to be perfect, I tried to multiplicate the accordion and it worked, but I need the active accordion close itself when I click on an other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is selector eq(0) and eq(1), they indicate your script would effect on just the first and second one of 'tiny-accordion' divs that it would found

It should be updated looks like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.tiny-accordion > div').hide();
  $('div.tiny-accordion > h3').click(function() {
    var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
    var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

    if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
      $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
        $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
      });
    } else {
       $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
    }
  }); 
});
```

On my jsfiddle, I have set for you as example for 3 sets of accordion, check it out and try by yourself.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m7xJB/10/)

Reference of eq http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/TF5AV/1/ 
I updated the jsfiddle by the last update in your question

Comment: Thanks a lot @Telvin Nguyen! I'm actually learning a javascript basics course, but I'm not arrived to jquery... thanks again.